# XSD validation of an element defined as an empty choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have encountered the XSD element definition with an empty choice:

```
   <xs:element name="Data">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:choice>
     </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
```

When I get the element instance:

```
<Data/>
```

within an XML document, some of the parsers (SoapUI, Oracle SOA 12c) evaluate it as an error:
Expected element(s) in element Data@http://www.namespace.com/ensc).

While others (Eclipse tools) evaluate the XML as Schema valid.

I wonder which evaluation result is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty `xs:choice` is [allowed in XSD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#element-choice):

```
<choice
  id = ID
  maxOccurs = (nonNegativeInteger | unbounded)  : 1
  minOccurs = nonNegativeInteger : 1
  {any attributes with non-schema namespace . . .}>
  Content: (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*)
</choice>
```

Notice that `Content:` may consist of an ***optional*** `annotation` followed by ***zero*** or more of `(element | group | choice | sequence | any)`.  Your XSD is therefore fine, and an XML document consisting of just `Data` would be valid against it.

Your XSD could be simplified to just

```
<xs:element name="Data">
  <xs:complexType/>
</xs:element>
```

Note, however, that it could not be further simplified to

```
<xs:element name="Data"/>
```

As that would actually allow `Data` to have *any* attributes and content model.